# Cannot access nested frame: permission denied to access property

Tags: javascript

I need to iterate all nested frames on a site and a piece of code is:

```
top.frames[0].document
```

I can access document property and search for elements there. The 'src' of this frame is: 'Pages/Login/index.aspx'.
in frames[0] there are a few nested frames.
I receive error: "permission denied to access property 'document'".

```
 top.frames[0].frames[1].document
```

I see that 'src' of top.frames[0].frames[1] containts full path with 'https:'
I think I cannot access document because of 'https'.
How can I access nested frame.document when it's 'src' is safe with 'https'?

Comment: If it is cross domain then you can't. Please note that domain changes when you change your protocol as well

Comment: Indeed, and see e.g. this reference: http://steveliles.github.io/cross_domain_inter_frame_communication_in_javascript.html